# Laravel group record by months and sum price

Tags: laravel

Hello i am trying to group record by months and sum price from orders

I tried something like this

```
       $order = Order::select(DB::raw('sum(price) as sums'))->groupBy(function($date) {
    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y-m');

});
```

but no luck, 
I wanna get collection which I could later implement in data-tables?

Comment: Try `->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y')"))`

Answer (score 15):

Please try with this:

```
  $orders = Order::select(
            DB::raw('sum(price) as sums'), 
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months")
  )
  ->groupBy('months')
  ->get();
```

Comment: This is only showing existing months. Is there any way i can get the index of other months! I have a chart where i need to show all the months, even if they have 0 values..

Comment: you can cross reference, make an array 1-12, then for each loop check if the months is exist, then put the value in the corresponding index, otherwise put zero.

Answer (score 10):

As an addition to **@Anowar Hossain** answer, you may use this solution to further get the index of other months regardless of whether they have values in them or not.

```
$orders = Order::select(
            DB::raw('sum(price) as sums'), 
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months"),
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as monthKey")
  )
  ->groupBy('months', 'monthKey')
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

If you're looking to provide data for the year only, you can consider doing this instead:

```
$orders = Order::select(
            DB::raw('sum(price) as sums'), 
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as monthKey")
  )
  ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
  ->groupBy('monthKey')
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
  ->get();
```

Then create an array with 12 zero values like this:

```
$data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

foreach($orders as $order){
    $data[$order->monthKey-1] = $order->sums;
}

return $data; // [0,10000,5000,7000,9000,0,0,0,0,15000,0,0]
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a little more coherent way to do @okafor-t-kosiso’s answer:

```php
$payments = Order::select( 
        \DB::raw('SUM(price) as subtotal'), 
        \DB::raw("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `created_at`) as year"),
        \DB::raw("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `created_at`) as month")
      )->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
      ->groupBy('month', 'year');
```

Results in something like:

```
|----------------------|
|subtotal |year |month |
|----------------------|
|234.32   |2022 |2     |
|654.02   |2022 |3     |
|35.00    |null |null  |
|----------------------|
```

Tested, and this will also actually aggregate on null date columns.