# Sum values of each parcels by months

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, sum, laravel-8

I'm stucked here. Someone please help meeee.

I need sum some values, grouped by month. But I don't have this values on DB. Just the start date, end date, value of the parcels and number of months.

Ex.
Expense

- Date of buy: 2022-01-15
- Value: 500.00
- Parceled: 10x
- Each parcel: 50.00
- End of parcels: 2022-11-15

Instead of inserting 10 lines in DB with each installment of each month. I would like to get the purchase date until the end of the installments and show in a graph the amount to be paid each month.

If I've another expense with the same value at month 03, for example. On month 04 my value by month of parcels will be 100.00, until the end of this new expense.

here is what i made:

```
        $parceled_expenses = Expense::whereYear('end_parcels', '>=', $thisYear)
            ->whereMonth('end_parcels', '>=', $thisMonth)
            ->select(
                DB::raw('sum(parcel_vl) as total'),
                DB::raw('month(end_parcels) as month')
            )
            ->groupBy('month');
```

This return (value of parcels => month):

```
             items: array:3 [
             126 => 5
             75 => 6
             50 => 12
```

With this data on my DB:

```
 date_pc    value   parcels parcel_vl   end_parcels 
 15/03/2022 500.00  10      50.00       15/01/2023
 16/04/2022 150.22  2       75.11       16/06/2022
 16/02/2022 150.00  3       50.00       16/05/2022
 02/03/2022 153.11  2       76.56       02/05/2022
 09/03/2022 125.00  2       62.50       09/05/2022
```

Thanks Advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question and try to explain in more detail what you are trying to do?  Summing a field by month is easy, there are many examples here on SO of doing that ([random eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201397/laravel-group-record-by-months-and-sum-price)), but AFAICT you need something a bit more complicated than that, though it isn't clear exactly what.

Comment: I would like to add the values ​​without having them inserted in the DB. I don't know if it's possible to make "value" / "parcels" and the value show every month until "end_parcels"