# How can I write the below pure SQL statement in laravel without using DB:raw

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to show the total price according to month. I know how to retrieve the data with pure SQL statements but I don't know a way to apply it inside Laravel. And also I don't want to use `DB::raw()`. I need help!! Below is the pure SQL statement.

```
SELECT month(dt.created_at) as Month,SUM(dp.price) as Total_Price
FROM datapack_transactions dt 
INNER JOIN datapack_packages dp ON dt.package_id=dp.id 
GROUP BY month(dt.created_at);
```

Below is the result of the above pure SQL statement.

[image: img]

I want to use the Laravel Eloquent instead of using `DB::raw()`.

Comment: Here is a similar issue that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201397/laravel-group-record-by-months-and-sum-price

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$orders = datapack_transactions::select(
            DB::raw('month(datapack_transactions.created_at) as Month'),
            DB::raw("SUM(datapack_packages.price) as Total_Price")
  )
  ->join('datapack_packages','datapack_packages.id','=','datapack_transactions.package_id')
  ->groupBy('datapack_transactions.created_at')
  ->get();

//Change model and columns as per yours
```